# DRY templates with jekyll

Tags: jekyll, dry

I have a product grid in my Jekyll site. I'd like the product grid to appear with different products in different places on my site, but I want to only store the HTML for the grid in one place.

I've looked into collections (and I'm using collections for something else in my project), but collections don't seem to be the right tool. The product grids aren't really semantically a "group" of anything.

Is there any other way I can avoid copying the product grid HTML into multiple places?

Note: I'm new to Jekyll.

Comment: A real example would help, but as It is described I would create a data file with the content and an include with the html using that data file so its contents can be included several times and its maintenance would be easier.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. So you should really try something and post a link to a simple repository showing what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an 'include' for this. This is the easiest way. I think that using a 'layout' with a 'collection' would be a more beautiful solution.

```
{% include productgrid.html %}
```

Note that you should put the 'productgrid.html' file in an '_includes' directory.

More info can be found here: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/
or in this walkthrough: http://jekyllcodex.org/getting-started/